# Kibana - Display times series of tweets posted - Twitter

Tags: twitter, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using the latest Kibana 4 / ES 1.4 version and I'm trying to display the number of tweets over time. My idea is to slice the 'created_at' field from the tweets documents.

The mapping defined for this field is the following

```
dynamic_templates": [
                    {
                        "created_at": {
                            "mapping": {
                                "locale": "US",
                                "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy",
                                "type": "date"
                            },
                            "match": "created_at"
                        }
                    },
```

...

I can create basic charts in Kibana (with term aggregates field) and overall seems to be working but I cannot display any trends with line charts or date histogram .with the created_at field.

**Below is the error**

```
ElasticsearchParseException[failed to parse date field [2014-10-13T23:35:31.450Z], 
tried both date format [EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy], and timestamp number]; nested:
IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: \"2014-10-13T23:35:31.450Z\"]; }
```

Thanks for your help,

Arnaud

Comment: How does `[EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy]` map to `[2014-10-13T23:35:31.450Z]`?

Comment: Hi Terence, I don't know. I'm using Zapier to post specific Tweets into ElasticSearch and I can see tweets are properly posted. See below an extract of the documents retrieved via ES I retrieved.     `{
    "_index": "tweets",
    "_type": "genesys",
    "_source": {
        "text": "Blah Blah Blah",
        "user": {
            "name": "Arnaud Lejeune",
            "created_at": "Wed Jan 05 17:39:08 +0000 2011",
            "time_zone": ""
        },
        "lang": "en",
        "created_at": "Mon Oct 13 15:47:23 +0000 2014",
    }
}`

Answer (score -1):

I'm unsure if the format of your date is correct but if it is I had a similar problem in ElasticSearch 1.4 that the parser wouldn't recognise the timestamp unless the timestamp was mapped  within properties:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/index/container/_mapping' -d'
{
"container" : {
"properties" : {
"@timestamp" : {"type":"date", "format": "dateOptionalTime"}
}
}
}'
```

Also may not be relavant to you but for a useful article for naming date conventions: http://joelabrahamsson.com/dynamic-mappings-and-dates-in-elasticsearch/

And the elastic search date format list: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html

Hope this helps!